# Display image from their corresponding path, which is saved in database

Tags: c#, sql, image, visual-studio-2010

In my application, I have stored images in a folder and saved their corresponding path in database using the following code:

```
if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
{
    string imagepath = pictureBox1.ImageLocation.ToString();
    string picname = imagepath.Substring(imagepath.LastIndexOf('\\'));
    string path = Application.StartupPath.Substring(0,Application.StartupPath.LastIndexOf("bin"));
    Bitmap imgImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image); 
    imgImage.Save(path + "\\Image\\" + picname + ".jpg");
    location = path + "'\'Image'\'" + picname;
}
else
    location = "";
```

My question is how can I display the images in picturebox from their corresponding path which is saved in database. In this code, the string variable location is saved in database. I'm using SQL server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2014/03/how-to-uploadstore-image-into-sql.html#.U2uEipKNkky check this link

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string ImagePath = "";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT photo FROM othersInfo WHERE empID='" + s + "'", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

con.Open();

SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if(dataReader.HasRows)
{
  dataReader.Read();
  ImagePath = Convert.ToString(dataReader["photo"]);
}

if (ImagePath != "") 
{
  Image image = Image.FromFile(ImagePath)
  pictureBox1.Image = image;
}
```

Comment: this is not working. Whenever I try to view image, It gives error saying unhandled exception.

Comment: What kind of exception?

Comment: viewProfile vp = new viewProfile();                              string pic = "SELECT photo FROM othersInfo WHERE empID='" + s + "'";
           if (pic != "")
           {
               
               vp.picViewProfile.ImageLocation = pic;
           }
           else
               vp.picViewProfile.Image = null;                         This code shows error imahe in picture box. I have also tried your code with the same query @Bayeni, but so far no luck.

Comment: I've edited my code to provide you with a complete solution, you just need to give it a connection string then it will do the work.